# Rails: How to check if "update_attributes" is going to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

To check if `buyer.save` is going to fail I use `buyer.valid?`:

```
def create
  @buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
  if @buyer.valid?
    my_update_database_method
    @buyer.save
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

How could I check if `update_attributes` is going to fail ?

```
def update 
  @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
  if <what should be here?>
    my_update_database_method
    @buyer.update_attributes(params[:buyer])
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it returns false if it was not done, same with `save`. `save!` will throw exceptions if you like that better. I'm not sure if there is `update_attributes!`, but it would be logical.

just do

```
if @foo.update_attributes(params)
  # life is good
else
  # something is wrong
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

### Edit

Then you want this method you have to write. If you want to pre check params sanitation.

```
def params_are_sanitary?
  # return true if and only if all our checks are met
  # else return false
end
```

### Edit 2

Alternatively, depending on your constraints

```
if Foo.new(params).valid? # Only works on Creates, not Updates
  @foo.update_attributes(params)
else
  # it won't be valid.
end
```

Comment: The main point that you are missing is that I want to execute `my_update_database_method` **before** calling to `update_attributes`, and `my_update_database_method` should be called **only if** `update_attributes` will succeed.

Comment: What function does it serve? You must have `save` working, which updates the database.

Comment: I have never encountered a situation where I had to do that. You have my sympathies.

Comment: I cannot call `update_attributes` directly because it will cause some database constraints violations. I must first change some database values, and I do that by calling `my_update_database_method`. But, in case `update_attributes` will fail (because of Rails validation), I don't want to call `my_update_database_method` (i.e. don't want to change any database values).

Comment: Sounds like you should rethink your database design sooner rather than later. This would be like if I had the constraint of fueling my car, only by walking to the gas station and bringing gas back home to my car. Would that method work? Yes. Is it painful? Yes.

Comment: You are right. I changed the design a little, and now it looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

The method `update_attributes` returns false if object is invalid. So just use this construction

```
def update
  if @buyer.update_attributes(param[:buyer])
    my_update_database_method
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

If your `my_update_database_method` has to be call only before `update_attributes`, then you shoud use merge way, probably like this:

```
def update
  @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
  @buyer.merge(params[:buyer])
  if @buyer.valid?
    my_update_database_method
    @buyer.save
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's right but it does not give you `@buyer.errors` .can you help with that . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best answer, but it seems to answer your question.

```
def self.validate_before_update(buyer)#parameters AKA Buyer.validate_before_update(params[:buyer])
# creates temporary buyer which will be filled with parameters
# the temporary buyer is then check to see if valid, if valid returns fail.
      temp_buyer = Buyer.new
# populate temporary buyer object with data from parameters
      temp_buyer.name = buyer["name"]
# fill other required parameters with valid data
      temp_buyer.description = "filler desc"
      temp_buyer.id = 999999 
# if the temp_buyer is not valid with the provided parameters, validation fails
    if  temp_buyer.valid? == false
        temp_buyer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          logger.info msg
        end        
# Return false or temp_buyer.errors depending on your need.
        return false
    end

return true
```

end

Answer (score 1):

you'd better check it in your model through a before_save

```
before_save :ensure_is_valid
private 
def ensure_is_valid
  if self.valid?
  else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same scenario - needed to know if record is valid and do some actions before update save. I've found out that there is `assign_attributes(attributes)` method which [`update`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) method uses before `save`. So nowadays it's likely correct to do:

```rb
def update
  @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
  @buyer.assign_attributes(params[:buyer])
  if @buyer.valid?
    my_update_database_method
    @buyer.save
  else
    ...
  end
end
```